# JQuery timer pop up after 2 minutes on website

Tags: jquery, popup, timed

I have a pop up which is timed to appear after 2 minutes on my web page, however I need it so that it will do this after 2 minutes on my website even if the user goes to another page. At the moment, it refreshes on each page load.

How would I do this? I presume some sort of session? Thanks in advance.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
   $.fancybox({
       overlayOpacity: 0.8,
       overlayColor: '#000',
       type: 'iframe',
       width: 625,
       height: 550,
       overflow: 'auto',
       padding: 0,
       href: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>feedback'
   });
}, 1000*60*2);
```

Comment: "goes to another page" do you mean inside your website or external page

Comment: Inside my website, sorry I should have stated that

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing. Did you accomplish it? Care to share, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easy way is to set a cookie with a timestamp and keep track of the time in that way. I found this jQuery cookie plugin that maybe help you: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: The link is broken. Know where I can find it? I am looking to do the same thing.